# Mi arreglo borra los valores tras ser llenado

Tags: c++, array, c++11, class

Mi código sirve para reservar los asientos de un vuelo determinado y que luego otros asientos sean llenados todo esta en una clase que selecciona los asientos y luego funciona con otra clase que selecciona los vuelos. Lo que hace la clase de asientos es generar un array para cada columna de asientos llenarlos de letras 'E' y tras los input del usuario llenar el determinado asiento con una 'R'.

[image: Se guarda el valor en el array]

Este proceso funciona bien para el primer input sin embargo cuando el usuario quiere llenar otro asiento se pierden los valores almacenados en el array.
[image: El valor se pierde]

```
    void seat_initializer (){

        static bool initialized;
        if (!initialized ){
            initialized = true;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
                column_A_NYCT13[i] = 'E';
                column_B_NYCT13[i] = 'E';
                column_C_NYCT13[i] = 'E';
                column_D_NYCT13[i] = 'E';
            }
        }
    }
    void seat_printer(){

        cout << "x AB | CD " << endl;
        cout << "0 " << column_A_NYCT13[0] << column_B_NYCT13[0] << " | " << column_C_NYCT13[0] << column_D_NYCT13[0] << endl;
        cout << "1 " << column_A_NYCT13[1] << column_B_NYCT13[1] << " | " << column_C_NYCT13[1] << column_D_NYCT13[1] << endl;
        cout << "2 " << column_A_NYCT13[2] << column_B_NYCT13[2] << " | " << column_C_NYCT13[2] << column_D_NYCT13[2] << endl;
        cout << "3 " << column_A_NYCT13[3] << column_B_NYCT13[3] << " | " << column_C_NYCT13[3] << column_D_NYCT13[3] << endl;
        cout << "4 " << column_A_NYCT13[4] << column_B_NYCT13[4] << " | " << column_C_NYCT13[4] << column_D_NYCT13[4] << endl;

    }
    void instruction_for_seats(){
        cout << "Now please see the order of the seats. \nThe columns A and D represents the window seats. \nThe columns B and C represents the hall seats.\nThe seats with the letter E represents the seats that are empty.\n"<< endl;
        seat_printer();
        cout <<endl;
        cout << "Please choose the correspondent letter for the column you want the seat for the flight NYCT13"<< endl;
    }

    void set_seats_window(char control_window) {
        int chosen_seat;
        if (control_window == 'A' || control_window == 'a') {
            for (int return_to_number = 1;;) {
                cout << "Please enter the number of the seat you want" << endl;
                cin >> chosen_seat;
                if (chosen_seat <= 4) {
                    cout << "You have chosen the seat A" << chosen_seat << "\nAre you sure you want to reserve this seat?\nType A to accept or C to cancell." << endl;
                    cin >> seat_confirmation_NYCT13;
                    if (seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'A' || seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'a'){
                        cout <<"Your selection was saved."<<endl;
                        column_A_NYCT13[chosen_seat] = 'R';
                        break;
                    }
                    if (seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'C' || seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'c'){
                        cout << "Your selection was cancelled"<<endl;
                    }
                }else {
                    cout << "Invalid entry.\a"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (control_window == 'D' || control_window == 'd') {
            for (int return_to_number = 1;;) {
                cout << "Please enter the number of the seat you want" << endl;
                cin >> chosen_seat;
                if (chosen_seat <= 4) {
                    cout << "You have chosen the seat A" << chosen_seat << "\nAre you sure you want to reserve this seat?\nType A to accept or C to cancell." << endl;
                    cin >> seat_confirmation_NYCT13;
                    if (seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'A' || seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'a'){
                        cout <<"Your selection was saved."<<endl;
                        column_D_NYCT13[chosen_seat] = 'R';
                        break;
                    }
                    if (seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'C' || seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'c'){
                        cout << "Your selection was cancelled"<<endl;
                    }
                }else {
                    cout << "Invalid entry.\a"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    void set_seats_hall(char control_hall){
        int chosen_seat;
        if (control_hall == 'B' || control_hall == 'b') {
            for (int return_to_number = 1;;) {
                cout << "Please enter the number of the seat you want" << endl;
                cin >> chosen_seat;
                column_B_NYCT13[chosen_seat] = 'R';
                if (chosen_seat <= 4) {
                    cout << "You have chosen the seat B" << chosen_seat << "\nAre you sure you want to reserve this seat?\nType A to accept or C to cancell."<< endl;
                    cin >> seat_confirmation_NYCT13;
                    if (seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'A' || seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'a') {
                        cout << "Your selection was saved for the reservation." <<endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'C' || seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'c') {
                        cout << "Your selection was cancelled.";
                    }
                } else {
                    cout << "Invalid entry. \a";
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (control_hall == 'C' || control_hall == 'c') {
            for (int return_to_number = 1;;) {
                cout << "Please enter the number of the seat you want" << endl;
                cin >> chosen_seat;
                column_C_NYCT13[chosen_seat] = 'R';
                if (chosen_seat <= 4) {
                    cout << "You have chosen the seat B" << chosen_seat << "\nAre you sure you want to reserve this seat?\nType A to accept or C to cancell."<< endl;
                    cin >> seat_confirmation_NYCT13;
                    if (seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'A' || seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'a') {
                        cout << "Your selection was saved for the reservation." <<endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'C' || seat_confirmation_NYCT13 == 'c') {
                        cout << "Your selection was cancelled.";
                    }
                } else {
                    cout << "Invalid entry. \a";
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }





private:
    char column_A_NYCT13 [4];
    char column_B_NYCT13 [4];
    char column_C_NYCT13 [4];
    char column_D_NYCT13 [4];
    char seat_confirmation_NYCT13;
```

Answer (score 2):

No presentas un ejemplo mínimo, luego es complicado decirte todo lo que tienes mal... pero si declaras un array tal que

```
char column_A_NYCT13 [4];
```

entonces dicho array será accesible en los índices `(0,3)`... y tu estás accediendo a `column_A_NYCT13[4]` en múltiples ocasiones:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
        column_A_NYCT13[i] = 'E';

cout << "4 " << column_A_NYCT13[4] << column_B_NYCT13[4] << " | " << column_C_NYCT13[4] << column_D_NYCT13[4] << endl;

// ...
```

Con eso solo consigues escribir fuera de los límites del array y modificar la memoria de otras variables... lo raro es que tu programa no se vuelva loco del todo.

Si necesitas que el array tenga 5 posiciones, cambia el `4` por el `5` en la declaración:

```
char column_A_NYCT13 [5];
```

De esta forma tu código dejará de sobreescribir memoria de otras variables.

Si, en cambio, resulta que el ejercicio te pide que gestiones **4** asientos, entonces tendrás que dejar de escribir en la posición `4` del array. Por ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
//              ~~~~~ El bucle ahora itera en el rango (0, 3)

    column_A_NYCT13[i] = 'E';
```